# Android - Getting the handle to components in a Custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I am trying to create a custom dialog box on the click of an option in the menu. I go on to start a new activity with the Intent pointing to customTextMessageDialog.

I **am able to get the handle** to any of the widgets defined in my customdialog.xml file using code like "phoneNumber = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.customDialogPhoneNumber1);"

However, I **can't do anything with this handle**. The moment I try to setText() for an EditText handle or if I set an onClickListener for one of the buttons defined in my xml my application crashes. Any idea as to why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Also, why do I need to create an instance of Dialog first before calling findViewById on that instance?

```
public class customTextMessageDialog extends Activity
{
    EditText phoneNumber;
    EditText message;
    Button cancelButton;
    Button sendButton;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    phoneNumber = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.customDialogPhoneNumber1);
    //phoneNumber.setTextColor(R.color.gray);
    //phoneNumber.setText("ex: 4127214544");
    message = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.customDialogMessage1);
    cancelButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.customDialogCancelButton1);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();

        }
    });
    sendButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.customDialogPhoneNumber1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are setting the `Activity`'s contentView to `customDialog`. You need to set the layout of your dialog to that layout. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).

Do this:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing that out. I made the change. However, my code still crashes when I try to modify the handle to the various elements I have.