# Android - Modifying the handle to something in a Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Getting the handle to components in a Custom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072632/android-getting-the-handle-to-components-in-a-custom-dialog)

I asked a similar question earlier. However, my code still crashes when I try to modify the handle to one of my elements defined in my customDialog

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);

    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Send Message");
    EditText phoneNumber = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.customDialogPhoneNumber1);
    phoneNumber.setText("Hello");
```

If I just remove the phoneNumber.setText("...") , the code will stop crashing and the dialog box shows up. However, I do need to get stuff form the handles to the various elements.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Instead you should have mentioned/updated the same in your previous question. Dont worry, somebody will sure provide answer. Its not preferable to ask redundant question here.

Comment: Sorry Paresh - I ll make sure I won't do that again. I am pretty new to stackoverflow..

Comment: please Don't say sorry to me, i just make you aware about this community. You should read this FAQs first: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask, Don't worry it happens as you are new to SO.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

create a class that extends dialog and in its onCreate do the setContentView and instantiation of buttons, etc. 
example:

```
public CustomDialog(Context context) {
  super(context);
}

Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_left);
}

public void setBListener(View.OnClickListener bListener) {
  b.setOnClickListener(bListener);
}
```

in your activity:

```
CustomDialog d = construct your custom dialog
OnClickListener onBClick = construct your onclicklistener
d.setBListener(onBClick);
```